# Array not storing the required parameter

Tags: php, xml, database, arrays, pdo

I am currently trying to post the value of xml title to an array which in turn will be used to save a holiday. I am still getting no error messages and have used a var_dump to gather the following infomation. (ticked a few check box's relating to reading the RSS feed)

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" [1]=> string(21)"{$currentItem->title}" [2]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" [3]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" [4]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" [5]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" [6]=> string(21) "{$currentItem->title}" } :S
```

This to me shows that the array side is working but it is not holding the information set within the value parameters for the check box as all strings are 21?. 
21 is the number of characters between the quotes of the value of saveBox!!

Section from index.php

```
$index = 1;
    foreach ($allHolidays as $currentItem)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            if (isset($_SESSION['login']))
                {
                    echo '<td valign="top">';
                    //echo '<input type="hidden" name="guid$index" value="{$currentItem->guid}">';name="saveBox$index[]"
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="saveBox[]" value="{$currentItem->title}">';
                    echo '</td>';
                }
            echo '<td>';
            echo "<p><a href=\"{$currentItem->link}\">{$currentItem->title}</a><br/>";
            echo "{$currentItem->description}<br/>";
            echo "{$currentItem->pubDate}<br/></p>";
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $index++;
        }
```

saveProcess.php

```
<?php   
    header("refresh:555; url='index.php'");
    session_start();

    echo "Thank you for saving a holiday";
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="saveBox[]" value="'.
    htmlspecialchars($currentItem->title).'">';
    include "top.php";
    var_dump($_POST['saveBox']);

    try
    {

        foreach ($_POST['saveBox'] as $savedHoliday)
        {
            $user = $_SESSION['login'];
            $currentSave = $savedHoliday;
            $save = "channel/item[title=\"$currentSave\"]";
            $holidaysXML = simplexml_load_file('holidays.xml');
            $savePath = $holidaysXML->xpath($save);
            foreach($savePath as $currentSavePath)
                    {
                        echo "<p><a href='{$currentSavePath->link}'>{$currentSavePath->title}</a>"."<br\>".
                        "{$currentSavePath->description}"."<br\>".
                        "{$currentSavePath->pubDate}"."<br\></p>";

                        $insertSave = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `saved_holidays` (`subscriberID`, `link`, `pubDate`, `title`, `description`)
                        VALUES ('$user', '$currentSavePath->link', '$currentSavePath->pubDate', '$currentSavePath->title', '$currentSavePath->description')");

                        $insertSave->execute();
                    }

        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: I've read your 'question' three times now and can't make a thing of it...

Comment: I was trying to check my array to make sure the correct infomation was being held by the checkbox as i cant get it to store within the database. Turns out the check box is holding the correct infomation but still i cant store this info into my database and im not sure where iv gone wrong thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the construct `saveBox$index[]` wrong. You should simply name your inputs `saveBox[]` and forget the index. PHP will automatically give you an array when you read `$_POST['saveBox']` on the receiving side.

Don't forget that you should also call `htmlspecialchars` on all data you embed into HTML:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="saveBox[]" value="'.
     htmlspecialchars($currentItem->title).'">';
```

And:

```
foreach ($_POST['saveBox'] as $savedHoliday)
```

As an aside, you should *always* call `header` and `session_start` before you produce any output, so if `top.php` produces output it should move a few lines downwards.

Comment: iv changed my code to saveBox and var dumped the array and it seems to be holding the correct information not sure why its not being processed correctly as its giving me no error messages

Comment: The var_dump showed that the array is being passed through with 21 characters and 21 characters is the exact number of characters between the saveBox Value field. Do you have any idea why its saving the string and not the xml path ? thanks